# If $\theta_1$ satisfies $\sin \theta = k$, then $\theta_2 := \pi - \theta_1$ also satisfies the equation

Tags: trigonometry

> If $k$ is constant between $-1$ and $1$, the equation $\sin \theta= k$ has many roots.
>
> If $\theta_1$ is one root then another root is $\theta_2=\pi-\theta_1$.

***I don't understand above statement, why do we need to subtract from $\pi$? I'm even more confused when $\sin \theta=-k$.***

Comment: Is my edit correct?

Comment: Draw a unit circle,pick a random $k$ and try to find solutions for $\sin \theta=k$ do the solutions satisfy $\theta_2=\pi-\theta_1$?

Comment: That's a basic property of the sine function: $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin x$.

Comment: Picture the sine function as the $x$-value of your point on the unit circle, i.e. the horizontal distance to the $y$-axis.  Then travelling the unit circle clockwise or anti clockwise yields the exact same values, if you start at $(1,0)$.

Comment: May be it is dumb question, but still I'm not clear. I'm taking a Math correspondence course. The book has very little explanation about it. If you can point me to some good video and  google link, really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the diagram below.

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine]

By definition, the sine of an angle in standard position (vertex at the origin, initial side on the positive $x$-axis) is equal to the $y$-coordinate of the point where the terminal side of the angle intersects the unit circle.  Therefore, two angles have the same sine when the $y$-coordinates of the points where they intersect the unit circle are equal.  By symmetry, $\sin(\pi - \theta) = \sin\theta$.  Moreover, since coterminal angles intersect the unit circle at the same point, any angle coterminal with these angles will have the same sine.  Hence, if $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$, then
$$\varphi = \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = \pi - \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

By symmetry, the $y$-coordinate of the point where the terminal side of the angle $-\theta$ intersects the unit circle is equal in magnitude and opposite in sign to that where the terminal side of angle $\theta$ intersects the unit circle.  The same can be said of the angle $\pi + \theta$.  Hence, $\sin(-\theta) = \sin(\pi + \theta) = -\sin(\theta)$.  Since coterminal angles intersect the unit circle at the same point, angles coterminal with $-\theta$ or $\pi + \theta$ also have the same sine.  Hence, if $\sin\varphi = -\sin\theta$, then
$$\varphi = -\theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = \pi + \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition of sine function it is opposite side by hypotenuse or radius vector length. The y coordinate >0 in quadrants 1 and 2.so inverse functions can be $\theta$ and $\pi- \theta$, symmetric about y-axis.

Reflect radius vectors about the x-axis for negative argument.